# How to add ul with li by clicking event on a specific li using jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Make an HTML page with a UL element with 3 list items with text - A, B, C.

Clicking on any li element should add a child list to it with proper naming.

```
<html>
<ul>
    <li id="A">A</li>
    <li id="B">B</li>
    <li id="C">C</li>
    </ul>
</html>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        i=1, a=1;
        $('#A').click(function() {
            $('#A').append('<ul><li id="A'+a+'">A'+a+'</li></ul>');
            $('#A'+i).click(function() {
                j=1;
                $(this).append('<ul><li id="A'+j+i+'">A'+j+i+'</li></ul>');
                i++;
            });
            a++;
        });
        b=1;
        $('#B').click(function() {
            $(this).append('<ul><li id="B'+b+'">B'+b+'</li></ul>');
            b++;
        });
        c=1;
        $('#C').click(function() {
            $(this).append('<ul><li id="C'+c+'">C'+c+'</li></ul>');
            c++;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself to create this. Tbh, if you know a bit about either javascript or jquery it should be fairly simple to make

Comment: can you show html also

Comment: Your code is working fine, Can you please give more details

Comment: @mohitesachin217 I think the problem with the op's code is that it's not very dynamic and it's not working with many levels of ul/li

Comment: I have to print in proper format also. But I am unable to do that. You can check that YouTube video. @mohitesachin217

Comment: the link is not proper... please check the video link..

Comment: check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pJTws2zeZc

Comment: I didn't get the answer yet.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen answer is very proper , that's what I was trying to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it fairly simple like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.Alfa").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var parentli = $(this).parent();
    var thisText = $(this).text();

    if (parentli.find("ul").length == 0) {
      parentli.append("<ul></ul>");
    }

    var ul = parentli.find(">ul");
    var c = ul.find("> li").length + 1;
    ul.append("<li><a href='#'>" + thisText + c + "</a></li>")
  })
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.Alfa").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var parentli = $(this).parent();
    var thisText = $(this).text();

    if (parentli.find("ul").length == 0) {
      parentli.append("<ul></ul>");
    }

    var ul = parentli.find(">ul");
    var c = ul.find("> li").length + 1;
    ul.append("<li><a href='#'>" + thisText + c + "</a></li>")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Alfa">
  <li>
    <a href="#">A</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">B</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">C</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```